# asp.net DetailsView - AutoGenerate Columns

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I have a asp DetailsView control that I auto generate the fields.

There is one column that has an ID that is mapped to another table (foreign key).  It shows up in a textbox. I want that column to be displayed as a dropdownlist as indicated in my code example below.  This works fine, but the other column still shows the textbox with the ID in it.

My question is:
is it possible to use the auto generate and still hide columns you don't need or want to modify?

I hate to have to write code for every single column just because one column needs to use a TemplateField.

DetailsView

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server"
        DefaultMode="Edit" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1"
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateInsertButton="True">
        <Fields>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Authorization">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList2" Runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource2" CssClass="DropDown"
                        DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="AuthenticationId" SelectedValue='<%# bind("AuthenticationId") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp
        </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

DetailsView DataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="EntityNamespace.MyEntity" EnableFlattening="False" 
        EntitySetName="Routes" Include="Authentication"  Where="it.RouteId = @RouteId">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:RouteParameter Type="Int32" RouteKey="RouteId" Name="RouteId" />
        </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Dropdownlist DataSource

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="EntityNamespace.MyEntity" EnableFlattening="False" 
        EntitySetName="Authentications">
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can. Take a look at `AutoGenerateRows`. It says like this on msdn:

> Explicitly declared row fields can be used in combination with
>   automatically generated row fields. When both are used, explicitly
>   declared row fields are rendered first, followed by the automatically
>   generated row fields.

But you also have to consider that the rows are not in the field collection

> Automatically generated bound row fields are not added to the Fields
>   collection.

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.autogeneraterows.aspx)

Comment: I read the article, and it does not indicate that I can do what I desire. Therefore I am just going to assume that it can't be done, and that I have to bind all the fields myself. + 1 for effort